# select menu through javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am retrieving data from ajax and JSON request from another php page. I have fetched two array strings using json pasrse.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==20  
{
 var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=data.subject;
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=data.scriptID;
}
```

PHP:

```
for($i=0;$i<$scriptscount;$i++){
   $scriptID[] = $currentscript[$i]['scriptID'];
}

for($i=0;$i<$scriptscount;$i++){
   $subject[] = $currentscript[$i]['subject'];
}

echo json_encode(array(
    'scriptID'=> $scriptID,
    'subject'=> $subject
));
```

The problem is, I am getting two separate array with comma. But, I want to make select menu in the current form, by passing the $scriptID as value and $subject as text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = array();

foreach ($scriptscount as $sc) {
    $json[] = array("script" => $sc['scriptID'], "subject" => $sc['subject']);
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Thanks.. And what will be in the javascript code to retrieve it?

Comment: @user2696691 iterate over the array.  Each array element will be an object with `script` and `subject` properties

Comment: Right now, I am getting undefined.

Comment: previously, I was having,
`echo json_encode(array(
    'script'=> $script
));`

AND

`var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = data.script;`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the php as follows:

```
for($i=0;$i<$scriptscount;$i++){
   $arr['script'][] = $currentscript[$i]['scriptID'];
   $arr['subject'][] = $currentscript[$i]['subject'];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

For using this for select box generation:

```
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML= "<select>";
for(x in data.script)
{
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML + "<option value="+data.script[x]+">"+data.subject[x]+"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML + "</select>";
```

Comment: Can you check the contents of json on browser console. Use `console.log(data)` after the first line of selectbox generation, and check in browser console(using some inspector like firebug maybe).